# Creating chart from big.matrix in R

Tags: r, memory, charts, bigdata

I'm struggling with big data file in R (more than 10GB) and using big.memory package. 
It works well for some calculations but I can't create any serious chart from chosen column. ggplot return the message that it can't create anything from S4 object
Any ideas how to create line chart from pointer?